# Issue with Angular testing while testing a sort function

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting, testing, jasmine

I have a sort function which takes an array of strings and then sorts an array of objects by their first property using this array.

The sort function works as intended. The component owns the function and since it needs to only be sorted a certain way the function doesn't take arguments, it simple uses the array which is a property of the component and sorts the array of objects which is also a property of that same component.

IE:

```
order = ['a', 'b', 'c']
arrayToSort = [
{name: b, color: blue},
{name: c, color: green},
{name: a, color: orange}
]
```

This is background for the issue. I have an angular test which tests the function, runs it and then expects the array to match a sorted array. What seems to happen is it either doesn't get sorted or Angular/Jasmine jumbles it before the expect.

I've tried:
Fixture.detectChanges();
fakeAsync and inside that running tick() and flushMicrotasks()
Even using setTimeout

I'm not sure what is happening and why the test is failing. See below for a screenshot of the failed test and also the code.

```
  describe('the setRingOrder method', () => {
    it(
      'should set the order of the rings correctly',
      waitForAsync(() => {
        const fakeRings: Array<RingModel> = [
          { name: 'adopt', color: '' },
          { name: 'trial', color: '' },
          { name: 'hold', color: '' },
          { name: 'asses', color: '' },
        ];
        const ringsInOrder: Array<RingModel> = [
          { name: 'adopt', color: '' },
          { name: 'asses', color: '' },
          { name: 'trial', color: '' },
          { name: 'hold', color: '' },
        ];
        component.rings = fakeRings;

        component.setRingOrder();

        expect(component.rings).toEqual(ringsInOrder);
      })
    );
  });
```

[Test Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qtij.png)

For good measure I'll show the sort function too, but keep in mind it works as intended in the app.

```
  setRingOrder(): void {
    this.ringOrder.forEach((ringForOrdering) => {
      this.rings.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.name.toLowerCase() === ringForOrdering.toLowerCase()) {
          return -1;
        } else if (b.name.toLowerCase() === ringForOrdering.toLowerCase()) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    });
  }
```

Edit: Just want to state I googled for various help and nothing that came back quite matched my issue...

Answer (score 1):

You just want to test the functioning of `setRingOrder` which is isolated in the component. You can create the instance of that component and assign the property exist in it and then you can run the function. You know the input given and the expected output which can help you to test it.

```
describe('the setRingOrder method', () => {
    it(
      'should set the order of the rings correctly',
      waitForAsync(() => {
        const fakeRings: Array<RingModel> = [
          { name: 'adopt', color: '' },
          { name: 'trial', color: '' },
          { name: 'hold', color: '' },
          { name: 'asses', color: '' },
        ];
        const ringsInOrder: Array<RingModel> = [
          { name: 'adopt', color: '' },
          { name: 'asses', color: '' },
          { name: 'trial', color: '' },
          { name: 'hold', color: '' },
        ];

        const component: ComponentType = new ComponentName();
        component.rings = fakeRings;
        // component.ringsInOrder set this too.
        component.setRingOrder();
        expect(component.rings).toEqual(ringsInOrder);
      })
    );
  });
```

If you need more information, you can check on [this](https://medium.com/@bencabanes/angular-component-testing-with-examples-7c52b2b7035e) post.

Comment: Hi Apoorva. I have created the component in the beginning of the testing file, as you can see I'm calling it with component.setRingOrder();. My issue is it isn't sorting properly for some reason  within the test.

Comment: What does it mean properly in the test? Does it throw an error or resulting different o/p? Just to know what is rings in the component? I guess you are using two properties `ringOrder` and `rings` and you need to set both of them to get correct results.

Comment: Hi Apoorva I  added a screenshot of the error with the initial post. RingOrder is set when the component is created using an export array like this: ringOrder: string[] = RingOrder;

Comment: when we configure the testbed for the component we does the same. Can you add the component code and the sample data which you pass on to sort method. I would like to look that to comment further.

Comment: Are you able to fix the issue or still lingering on it?

Comment: Hi Apoorva I'm still having the issue and everything is in the original comment. Short of me pasting the whole component...

Answer (score 0):

Due to the issue here the type of test wsas changed like so

```
describe('the setRingOrder method', () => {
    it(
      'should set the order of the rings correctly',
      waitForAsync(() => {
        const fakeRings: Array<RingModel> = [
          { name: 'adopt', color: '' },
          { name: 'trial', color: '' },
          { name: 'hold', color: '' },
          { name: 'asses', color: '' },
        ];
        component.rings = fakeRings;
        spyOn(component.rings, 'sort');

        component.setRingOrder();

        expect(component.rings.sort).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(
          component.rings.length
        );
      })
    );
```